# How to round to the nearest date using JavaScript Date Object

Tags: javascript, date

How to round to the nearest date using JavaScript Date Object?

I have `2020-10-14T18:10:48.960Z` and I want it a function that returns `2020-10-15T05:00:00.000Z` which is the closest date in my timezone CST.  Or if I give it `2020-10-14T16:10:48.960Z` I want it to return `2020-10-14T05:00:00.000Z`.

Comment: In other words, if the given date, converted to *your* time zone, is before 12:00 noon then you want to get the beginning of that day, and if the date is on or after 12:00 noon then you want to get the beginning of the next day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to just add 12 hours to the date, then truncate the time portion.  This has the effect of rounding to the nearest date (anything before noon just has the time truncated, anything after goes to the next day, then has the time truncated).

```js
let d = new Date();
// add 12 hours to the date
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (12*60*60*1000));
// truncate the time
d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: To deal with daylight saving changeover days, better to add 12 hours using `date.setHours(date.getHours() + 12)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the hour and if it's before 12, set to the time to 00:00:00. If it's 12 or after, set the time to 24:00:00, e.g.

```js
let d = new Date();
d.setHours(d.getHours() < 12? 0 : 24, 0,0,0);

console.log(d.toISOString() + '\n' + d.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//this code will round to the nearest date

const roundToNearestDay = (date) => {
  let isPastNoon = date.getHours() >= 12
  if (isPastNoon)
    //if first parameter > 23, will increment date +1
    date.setHours(24,0,0,0)
  else
    date.setHours(0,0,0,0)
  return date
}

let nearestDay = roundToNearestDay(new Date())
console.log(nearestDay)
```